# What is the difference between la and li in opcodes in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

For example in this code :

```
#display message
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Message


#promt user to enter name
li $v0, 8 
la $10, username
li $a1, 20
syscall

#display the name
li $v0, 4
la $a0, userName
syscall
```

I am very confused about what `li` (load immediate) and `la` (load address) really mean.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They're fairly similar, as both are (mostly) used for loading immediate values. Both of them are also *pseudo-instructions*, so it's really up to each assembler that supports them to determine exactly how they should function.

---

`li` stands for Load Immediate and is a convenient way of loading an immediate up to 32 bits in size. Instructions like `addi` and `ori` can only encode 16-bit immediates, so the assembler may translate `li` into multiple instructions.

For example, `li $t0,0x12345678` might become:

```
lui $at, 0x1234 
ori $t0, $at, 0x5678
```

So it's just a way to save you from writing those two instructions, and instead letting the assembler working that out for you.

There's really no reason why e.g. `li $t0, Message` wouldn't be supported, since labels are also immediates, but some assemblers might not accept labels for `li`.

---

`la` stands for Load Address. It can be used to load integer constants just like `li`, e.g. `la $t0,0x1234678`. But it also works with labels: `la $t0, Message  # t0 = address of Message`.
Some assemblers may also allow you to do things like `la $t0, 8($t1)  # t0 = t1 + 8`.

---

When you'd use `li` and when you'd use `la` depends on the context. If the value you're loading is going to be used as an address you would typically use `la` to load it, and otherwise you'd typically use `li`. Since they are partially interchangable it's really up to you, but other people might find your code strange-looking if you use `la` all the time to load integer constants.