# What is the difference between la and li in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I started learning Assembly (Mips) and I'm trying to figure out what the difference is between the 2 inscriptions (Li to LA)
What I can not understand, that if I do the LA command that it is actually to loadaddress into a "cell" (i assume it's in the "Date segement") within which there is a value (a kind of index in a high - level programming language)
My question is where is this address stored and where does it point?
It refers to an address (0x0040000) and from there I get an address the "index" into a memory register?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between la and li in opcodes in MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313072/what-is-the-difference-between-la-and-li-in-opcodes-in-mips)

Comment: hey! I saw the answer, but still did not understand what "address" means in mips

Comment: There's nothing special about addresses in MIPS, as compared to x86, any other processors, or in the C language with pointers.  An address is just a number, which we can use to refer to a memory location to store & later recall; this is called dereference.  An address is just a number, so for example, we can add 1 to an address to refer to a different memory location.

Comment: If you know the address of some memory location numerically you can use `li` to materialize that address/number in a register.  If you know of some memory location symbolically, i.e. by a label name, then you can use `la` to materialize its address/number in a register.

Comment: `la` loads an address into a *register*, not into one cell of memory (1 byte).  A register is 4 bytes wide.  "memory register" is an oxymoron: registers and memory are two separate kinds of storage, only memory has addresses (i.e. can be indexed / accessed indirectly).

Answer (score 0):

LA is to load an address (generally used for labels/arrays/etc)
LI is to load an immediate value into a register (generally it tends to be a number) - via pseudo command

[image: MARS]

in this case it translated to the same command, but in general the difference is procedure and practice... basically it is the standard thing to do.